# Determine if the convergence of $\sum|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ implies the convergence of $\sum |a_n|$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)$ a sequence of reals with the property that $\sum a_n$ is finite.
>
> Determine if the convergence of $\sum|a_{n+1} - a_n|$ implies the convergence of $\sum |a_n|$.

After contemplating it, I assume it is indeed true. My attempts to prove it failed where the hardest part for me is using the convergence of $\sum a_n$.

So far my main observation I suppose is
that for each $m > n > 1$ we have $ |a_n| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m} |a_k - a_{k-1}| $

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't try to prove it, because it's not true.

Comment: @DavidMoews, any counter examples?

Comment: As is often the case, $\frac{1}{n}$ is a good enough counter example.

Comment: $a_n=1/n$ is not a counterexample, because $\sum_n 1/n$ is not finite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't follow.  For one counterexample, let $b_n$ be any sequence of positive integers such that $\sum_n b_n^{-1}$ converges, let $c_n$ be any sequence of positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n=0$ but $\sum_n c_n$ diverges, and take the sequence
$$(a_n)=(c_1/b_1, \dots, c_1/b_1, -c_1/b_1, \dots, -c_1/b_1, c_2/b_2, \dots, c_2/b_2, -c_2/b_2, \dots, -c_2/b_2, c_3/b_3, \dots,)$$
where each string of values $\pm c_n/b_n$ occurs $b_n$ times.